# Change position of object properties by matching other array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Object

```
var $data = {
  D_1_AA_Changes.xml: "This is a string", 
  D_2_Compare_AA_Changes.xml: "This is a string"
}
```

I need to match the property with another array I have like this:

```
var list_match = ["D_2_Compare_AA_Changes","D_1_AA_Changes"];
```

I need to match the `list_match` with `$data` property and arrange the `$data` object as list_match array values.

so after matching I have to arrange `$data` like this:

```
$data = {
  D_2_Compare_AA_Changes.xml: "This is a string",
  D_1_AA_Changes.xml: "This is a string"
}
```

So I need the final result like the above

Comment: why not take the array for accessing order of the array?

Comment: finally i need the object after matching the order... can you provide me any example

Comment: There is no 'order' notion in a javascript object. You don't know how the properties are internally managed and cannot rely on the 'position' you gave them when inserting in the object.

Comment: This data object is a dynamic object created from some xml file dear, so i dont have access to that file...I am just getting this data object and needs to arrange in order i provided above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do this in a fully-compliant ES2015+ JavaScript engine, but in general, it's best to treat object properties as being unordered, since many object property operations (like `for-in`), even in ES2015+, are not guaranteed to follow the order that is used by the new ones (like `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`, `JSON.stringify`). Order is also not necessarily maintained when you serialize and deserialize (for instance, going to and from JSON). It *may* be, but it isn't guaranteed to be.* Relying on unguaranteed behavior leads to subtle, time-wasting bugs.

But if you want to do it on an ES2015+ engine, create a new object and add those properties in the order you want them to be in:

```js
const $data = {
  "D_1_AA_Changes.xml": "This is a string",
  "D_2_Compare_AA_Changes.xml": "This is a string"
};

var list_match = ["D_2_Compare_AA_Changes","D_1_AA_Changes"];

console.log("before", JSON.stringify($data));

const $newData = {};
for (const entry of list_match) {
  const name = entry + ".xml";
  $newData[name] = $data[name];
}

console.log("after", JSON.stringify($newData));
```

Note that it works in this case because the property names don't look like array indexes, and these are "own" properties. Property names that look like array indexes aren't listed in creation order like other property names are.

So again: Strongly recommend not trying to use object property order.

More reading:

- [The spec on the order of "own" properties in an object](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys)
- [The spec on the order of "own" and inherited properties in an object](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-enumerate-object-properties)
- [Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties) the answers to which outline the operations that **do** and **don't** follow property order

---

* `JSON.stringify` is guaranteed to follow the order, but the *consumers* of that JSON are not, necessarily.

Comment: Great solution T.J Crowder, Now i am your fan , Thanks.... You are awesome

Answer (score 0):

You can use the order in the array to access the object properties like so

```
list_match.forEach(function(key) {
  var myData = $data[key];
  /* you can check that `myData` is not undefined */
})
```

Comment: oh sorry it contains 0 and 1 as the key

Comment: which object contains 0 and 1 ? Could you update your first post so ?